# How to loop through column in excel until an empty cell

Tags: python, excel, string, xlrd, nonetype

I have written some python code that loops through an excel sheet and extracts the strings from the cells. I wish the loop to stop once it reaches an empty cell. I can get this to work if I put a string in the last cell eg "Stop" and have the code `while sheet.cell_value(r, c) != "Stop"` where `r` and `c` are the rows and column.  However, if I change to `!= ''` it doesn't work. The loop will run whilst the cells have something in them. Once the code reaches the empty cell where I want it to stop, I get the error message: *"IndexError: list index out of range"*

Any help appreciated!

```
r = 14
c = 2
      
while sheet.cell_value(r, c) != '':
    # do something....
    r+=1
```

Comment: Are you working with `xlrd` or some other library?

Comment: An empty cell has a value equal to `None` , not an empty string.

Comment: Thanks  Vitalizzare  I'm using xlrd

Comment: Thanks moken. If I use .value I get an error message saying no value because it is looking for a string

Comment: Hi Moken, I have tried using "while sheet.cell_value(r, c) is not None:" but this is doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by _"it doesn't work"_?

Comment: The loop will run whilst the cells have something in them. Once the code reaches the empty cell where I want it  to stop, I get the error message: IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>xlrd 2.0.1</kbd>

As far as `xlrd` is used, empty cells are filled with empty strings, not `None` (*you may need to take into account `ctype` of the cell to avoid confusion with empty text*). So the code is correct in this aspect. But the data area looks differently from what you can see in Excel. Unlike Excel, which always displays all possible cells on the screen ([exact restrictions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) depend on version), the xlrd reader only addresses the *used range*. If there are no empty cells in the used area, then the posted code will exceed the limits of the allowed address space at some point. So it would be correct to check not only for empty cells, but also for row and column constraints, which are `sheet.nrows` and `sheet.ncols`:

```
r = 14
c = 2
      
while r < sheet.nrows and sheet.cell_value(r, c) != '':
    # do something....
    r+=1
```

We can also use [sheet.col_values](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=col_values#xlrd.sheet.Sheet.col_values) for the same purpose:

```
EXIT_VALUE = ''
for x in sheet.col_values(c, start_rowx=r):
    if x == EXIT_VALUE:
        break
    ...
```

In order not to confuse empty cells with empty text, you need to iterate not through cell values, but through cells themselves and check their сtype property:

```
from xlrd import XL_CELL_EMPTY

r, c = 14, 2
for cell in sheet.col(c, start_rowx=r):
    if cell.ctype == XL_CELL_EMPTY:
        break
    ...

# or using a while loop, incrementing the row number

while r < sheet.nrows and sheet[r, c].ctype != XL_CELL_EMPTY:
    ...
    r += 1
```

Comment: Vitalizzare. Thank you so much. That seems to have fixed it. Thanks for the clear explanation.